# Fetching Data from JSON in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I am new to JSON query in Postgresql.
Below is my practice so far

```
INSERT INTO property_graph(node,edges_property)
SELECT 'E','{
 "Owner" : 
  [
     {"Edgeid":1,  "Weight": 10, "Active":1, "OutgoingVertexid": "A", "IncomingVertexid": ""},
     {"Edgeid":2,  "Weight": 20, "Active":1, "OutgoingVertexid": "B", "IncomingVertexid": ""}
  ],
  "Supporter" : 
  [
     {"Edgeid":3,  "Weight": 30, "Active":0, "OutgoingVertexid": "C", "IncomingVertexid": ""},
     {"Edgeid":4,  "Weight": 40, "Active":0, "OutgoingVertexid": "D", "IncomingVertexid": ""}
  ]
}'
```

i am trying to fetch data in below format:

[image]

i tried to use below query but not getting proper output:

```
SELECT node,
edges_property::JSON -> 'Owner' -> 'OutgoingVertexid' AS Owner_OutgoingVertexids,
edges_property::JSON -> 'Supporter' -> 'OutgoingVertexid' AS Supporter_OutgoingVertexids
FROM property_graph
```

Please help me out on my query and also suggest me if i storing wrong json format.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...not getting proper output" - what results did you expect, and what *are* you getting?

Comment: You'll need to use `json_array_elements` to iterate the array, probably in a subquery to access the `OutgoingVertexid` in  each element and then accumulate them back into a string or array.

Comment: SELECT node,
edges_property::JSON -> 'Owner' -> 'OutgoingVertexid' AS Owner_OutgoingVertexids,
edges_property::JSON -> 'Supporter' -> 'OutgoingVertexid' AS Supporter_OutgoingVertexids
FROM property_graph                                                                                                       i used above query...but getting null in both Owner_OutgoingVertexids & Supporter_OutgoingVertexids columns.

Comment: @VBAGuy You're getting `null` because `edges_property::JSON -> 'Owner'` is an array, not an object on which you can access the `OutgoingVertexid`. (If you're on postgres 12, you could try a json path though, which automatically unnests arrays)

Comment: @Bergi...I am on Postgres 10 ...so cannot use json path...let me try to get some details on json_array_elements ....that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seperate the parts `edges_property::JSON -> 'Owner'` and `-> 'OutgoingVertexid'`. Leave the second one in the second step with `->>` operator and containing `string_agg()` function :

```
WITH property_graph2 AS
(
SELECT node, 
       edges_property::JSON -> 'Owner' AS Owner_OutgoingVertexids, 
       edges_property::JSON -> 'Supporter' AS Supporter_OutgoingVertexids 
  FROM property_graph
)
SELECT node, 
       string_agg(distinct j1.value ->> 'OutgoingVertexid',',') AS Owner_OutgoingVertexids,
       string_agg(distinct j2.value ->> 'OutgoingVertexid',',') AS Supporter_OutgoingVertexids
  FROM property_graph2
 CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(Owner_OutgoingVertexids) j1 
 CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(Supporter_OutgoingVertexids) j2 
 GROUP BY node
```

An alternative option for your case, containing `json_each()` function, might be the following :

```
SELECT node, 
       string_agg(Owner_OutgoingVertexids,',') AS Owner_OutgoingVertexids,
       string_agg(Supporter_OutgoingVertexids,',') AS Supporter_OutgoingVertexids
  FROM
  (
   SELECT CASE 
          WHEN k='Owner' THEN 
              json_array_elements(v)->>'OutgoingVertexid'
           END AS Owner_OutgoingVertexids, 
          CASE 
          WHEN k='Supporter' THEN 
              json_array_elements(v)->>'OutgoingVertexid'
           END AS Supporter_OutgoingVertexids, 
          t.*,
          js.*
     FROM property_graph t
    CROSS JOIN json_each(edges_property::json) AS js(k,v)
   ) q 
 GROUP BY node
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=9ec60c286d59c12b237a0868c9313091)</kbd>

Comment: @Barbaros...Thanks for your reply. I used first method as it looks more readable using CTE. I did bit modification and used two query separately for json_array_elements(Owner_OutgoingVertexids) j1 and json_array_elements(Supporter_OutgoingVertexids) j2 as one of my test case was failing if i use both cross join in single query. Your query was giving me result if i have both "Owner" and "Supporter" in JSON...my test case can either have "Owner"/"Supporter"/"Owner" and "Supporter".